# Sampling high impedance, higher voltage source

Tags: adc, high-impedance

I have a low voltage ADC. How do I sample a high impedance signal that has a voltage higher than my ADC can handle?

I understand the concept of buffering the ADC input to deal with the high impedance aspect. I also understand the concept of using a voltage divider to lower a voltage range. But a voltage divider is a current sink, and my signal is high impedance.

Is there a general strategy? Do people use a voltage divider and just pick resistances that are high enough to meet an error goal?

To throw some numbers at this, my ADC can measure GND to 3.3V (it's in a MCU). The signal of interest is 0-5V, and I'd like to be able to sample signals having an impedance of up to 500 kOhm. My sampling frequency is low (in the order of 1 Hz).

Comment: Buffering will convert the high-impedance signal into low-impedance signal. From there, using voltage dividers becomes less problematic *(But still, you should should take the input behaviour of the ADC, though)*. Plus, they'll be no longer driven by the high-impedance source so shouldn't be a problem from your high-impedance signal generator. One of the most important thing to take into account is the input bias currents of the op amp / buffer as they'll affect the signal seen by the op amp.

Comment: How high frequency is the signal? Have you tried to simulate your divider with the high impedance source modeled?

Comment: @winny Low frequency (in the order of 1 Hz). I'd like to accommodate a wide range of source impedances, so before I settle on an impedance number/spec I'd like to get a better grasp on the theory

Comment: Good, then you are deep into the resistive only domain. What's your source impedance?

Comment: The implementation will depend on what are the actual numbers of the voltages and impedances involved. And also how often you want to take a sample. Please provide actual numbers, othetwise we don't know if your high voltage high impedance is 5V and 100kohm or 5kV and 500Mohm.

Comment: @winny Edited to add details. Thank you

Comment: @Justme Edited to add details. Thank you